# Functions and Dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def build_dictionary(infile):  
    count_dict={}  
    for line in infile:  
        line=line.strip()  
        if len(line) and line[0]!="-":  
            lst=line.split(",")  
            lastname=lst[0].strip()  
            for lastname in lst:  
                if lastname not in count_dict:  
                    count_dict[lastname]=1  
                else:  
                    count_dict[lastname]=count_dict[lastname]+1  
                return count_dict  


def main():  
    import os.path  
    while True:  
        try:  
            name1=input("Enter input name:")  
            infile=open(name1,"r")  
            result=build_dictionary(infile)  
            print(result)  
            break  
        except:  
            print("Error in code")  


main()
```

I have this program and I want it to take a file that contains last name,first name, take the last names and see how many times they appear in the dict. the only problem i have is it counts the first lastname then stops, whyy isnt it going through the entire dictionary

Comment: Why do you have `for lastname in lst`? The binding shadows `lastname=list[0].strip()`, and in any event lst contains both the first and last names from that line (the outcome of `lst=line.split(",")`). I think that you want to drop that line and proceed directly into the if statement. It should not be the cause of your error, however.

Comment: def build_dictonary(infile):
    astring=infile.strip("")
    count_dict={}
    alist=[]
    alist=infile.split()
    for lastname in alist:
        if lastname not in count_dict:
            count_dict[lastname]=1
        else:
            count_dict[lastname]=count_dict[lastname]+1  



this is what I having working but i dont know how to incorporate the for line in infile stuff. your help is reeally appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Replace your build_dictionary method with this:

```
def build_dictionary(infile):
    count_dict={}
    for line in infile:
        line=line.strip()
        if len(line) and line[0]!="-":
            lst=line.split(",")
            lastname=lst[0].strip()
            if lastname not in count_dict:
                count_dict[lastname]=1
            else:
                count_dict[lastname]=count_dict[lastname]+1
    return count_dict
```